# Свойства в Java

Tags: java, c#

У меня сравнительный вопрос по C# и Java. В C# есть свойства:

```
class SomeClass
{
    int SomeProperty { get; private set; }
}
```

А как в Java делается подобное?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Java это будет так (в случае someProperty типа int)

```
class SomeClass {
      private int someProperty;  

      public int getSomeProperty() {
         return someProperty;
      }
      public void setSomeProperty(int newProperty){
         someProperty = newProperty;
      }
}
```

[Здесь](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/java_csharp_comparison.html) можно найти более детальное сравнение Java и C#

Более компактный вариант

```
class SomeClass {
      private int someProperty;  

      public int getSomeProperty() {return someProperty;}
      public void setSomeProperty(int newProperty){someProperty = newProperty;}
}
```

Comment: В C# компактнее: 1 строчка вместо 7.

Comment: На самом деле, это был представлен более наглядный вариант (с моей точки зрения) ниже то же самое, но записано в 3 строчки. Если честно, особо сильной разницы не вижу. А так в качестве примера компактности можно вспомнить что-нибудь из функциональных языков программирования(Erlang, Haskel, Scala), где описание синтаксиса своего языка можно уместить примерно в 100 строчек...

Comment: Чем больше кода, тем его тяжелее писать и читать. Хорошо еще, если редактор берет на себя часть работы.

Comment: Возможно Вы правы в каком-то смысле, но я не считаю это главным. Гораздо более важным мне кажется хорошо продуманная структура приложения. Большая части производительности зависит не от использованного языка программирования, а от продуманной структуры приложения.

Comment: В java удобно писать такой класс, потому что в Intellij Idea есть шот-кат Alt+Insert - generate "Getter and Setter", остается только выбрать нужные филды и нажать Ок

Comment: В groovy подобное тоже делается в одну строчку.

Comment: Это не в idea есть, а вообще во всех основных Java-редакторах. И рефакторинги к ним тоже применимы. Соглащусь с Serg. Синтаксическая разница по большому счёту несущественна.

Comment: Утверждение про то, что чем меньше кода, тем проще его читать, 
в общем неверно. Перл. Есть хорошее правило 25 секунд:
если экран кода можно понять за 25 секунд - код хороший.

Comment: (Археология) вообще-то, разница в синтаксисе существенна. Сравните:

    player.car.speed++;

и

    getPlayer().getCar().setSpeed(getPlayer().getCar().getSpeed()+1);

Кто видит в этом только синтаксический сахар, кривит душой.

Answer (score 2):

В Java есть (не лишённый своих недостатков) проект Lombok, позволяющий писать ещё более лаконично:

```
@Data
class SomeClass {
   private int someProperty; 
}
```